# Camera for B&W?

Tags: camera-recommendation

Is there a camera out there (dSLR-class) that offer's a one-touch (or nearly) ability to view a shot in black and white?  Also, what about LiveView functionality with realtime black and white?

Comment: Hi marienbad, you have several questions open and you haven't marked any of the answers as 'accepted'.  Have you considered if any of your previous questions have been answered adequately? Thanks!

Comment: even my 6 year old D200s can record in B&W and display images as such on the screen.

Answer (score 4):

**Realtime B&W is available on all SLDs and SLRs with Live-View.**

It is also available on the Fuji X100 which is a (almost) compact camera with a sensor the same size (APS-C) as most DSLRs. Probably does not count as SLR-class unless you only consider the image quality.

Many entry-level DSLRs and even some pro ones now have in-camera effects or conversions which can convert to B&W. It is far from one-touch though, requiring 5 to 10 button presses.

Comment: Can the X100 do B&W in realtime in the viewfinder?

Comment: Yes. I tried that yesterday :) Simply set Film-Simulation to one of the B&W modes, see the review for details: http://www.neocamera.com/camera/fuji/x100/review

Answer (score 1):

Recent Nikon DSLRs like the D90 and D7000 that have Picture Controls, have a monochrome setting which will display B&W on the LCD.  If you shoot RAW you can override the picture control in post processing and still have a color image if you like.  JPGs would be produced in B&W.

I believe Live View will also display according to the picture control, so would display in monochrome.  I will have to try it and confirm.

They also have in-camera image editing, which you could access with a couple of touches if you set them up in a custom menu.